# What is the fastest algorithm for checking if a 14 digit number is prime?

Tags: performance, testing, primes, digit

I need the fastest possible program for primality check on a 14 digit(or bigger) number. I searched on multiple sites but i'm not sure the ones I found will work with numbers as big as this.

Comment: Miller Rabin can easily be made deterministic for small values (14 digits is small), and is very fast. For very small numbers, trial division is faster.

Comment: What do you need that for?  How many 14-digit numbers do you need to check?  Can you pick them from a small range?

Comment: It's just as easy to use the `(7)` base values that form a deterministic Miller-Rabin test for all values < `2^64`. Almost all candidates will fail the 2-SPRP test. The other lower bounds aren't much good...

My implementation (requires gcc / clang extension) is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brettyhale/mrtab/master/xperimental/prime64.c). See also: https://miller-rabin.appspot.com/

Comment: [This one is fast for 14-digit numbers](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib/blob/main/src/is-prime.ts).

Answer (score 6):

A 14-digit number is not very big as far as prime testing is concerned. When the number has some special structure, specialised tests may be available that are faster (e.g. if it's a Mersenne number), but in general, the fastest tests for numbers in that range are

1. Start trial division by some small numbers. If you plan to do many checks, it's worth to make a list of the `n` smallest primes, so that the trial division only divides by primes, for a single test, just avoiding even test divisors (except 2), and multiples of 3 (except 3), is good enough. What "small" means is up to interpretation, choices between 100 and 10000 for the cutoff seem reasonable, that many (few) divisions are still quickly done, and they find the overwhelming majority of composite numbers.
2. If the trial division has not determined the number as composite (or prime, if it's actually smaller than the square of the cutoff), you can use one of the fast probabilistic prime tests that are known to be definitive for the range you're interested in, the usual candidates are

   - the Baillie/Pomerance/Selfridge/Wagstaff test, a strong Fermat test for base 2, followed by a test for being a square and a (strong) Lucas test. That doesn't have false positives below 2<sup>64</sup>, so it's definitive for numbers with 14-18 digits.
   - strong Fermat tests for a collection of bases known to be definitive for the range considered. According to [Chris Caldwell's prime pages](http://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html), "If `n < 341,550,071,728,321` is a 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and 17-SPRP, then n is prime".

Somewhat slower, and considerably harder to implement, would be the fast deterministic general-purpose prime tests, APR-CL, ECPP, AKS. They should already beat pure trial division for numbers of 14 or more digits, but be much slower than the incidentally-known-to-be-correct-for-the-range probabilistic tests.

But, depending on your use-case, the best method could also be to sieve a contiguous range of numbers (If you want to find the primes between 10<sup>14</sup>-10<sup>9</sup> and 10<sup>14</sup>, for example, a sieve would be much faster than several hundred million fast individual prime tests).

Answer (score 5):

As Daniel Fischer notes, a 14-digit number isn't particularly large for primality testing. That gives you several options. The first is simple trial division:

```
function isPrime(n)
    d := 2
    while d * d <= n
        if n % d == 0
            return Composite
        d := d + 1
    return Prime
```

The square root of 10^14 is 10^7, so that might take a little while. Somewhat faster is to use a [prime wheel](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/05/08/wheel-factorization/):

```
struct wheel(delta[0 .. len-1], len, cycle)

w := wheel([1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6], 11, 3)

function isPrime(n, w)
    d := 2; next := 0
    while d * d <= n
        if n % d == 0
            return Composite
        else
            d := d + w.delta[next]
            next := next + 1
            if next == w.len
                next := w.cycle
    return Prime
```

That should speed up the naive trial division by a factor of 2 or 3 times, which might be sufficient for your needs.

A better option is probably a Miller-Rabin pseudoprimality tester. Start with a strong pseudoprime test:

```
function isStrongPseudoprime(n, a)
    d := n - 1; s := 0
    while d is even
        d := d / 2; s := s + 1
    t := powerMod(a, d, n)
    if t == 1 return ProbablyPrime
    while s > 0
        if t == n - 1
            return ProbablyPrime
        t := (t * t) % n
        s := s - 1
    return DefinitelyComposite
```

Each *a* for which the function returns `ProbablyPrime` is a *witness* to the primality of *n*:

```
function isPrime(n)
    for a in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17]
        if isStrongPseudoprime(n, a) == DefinitelyComposite
            return DefinitelyComposite
    return ProbablyPrime
```

As Fischer noted, for *n* < 10^14 this is perfectly reliable, according to a [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-204/S0025-5718-1993-1192971-8/) by Gerhard Jaeschke; if you want to test the primality of larger numbers, choose 25 witnesses *a* 
at random. The `powerMod(b,e,m)` function returns *b* ^ *e* (mod *m*). If your language doesn't provide that function, you can efficiently calculate it like this:

```
function powerMod(b, e, m)
    x := 1
    while e > 0
        if e % 2 == 1
            x := (b * x) % m
        b := (b * b) % m
        e := floor(e / 2)
    return x
```

If you're interested in the math behind this test, I modestly recommend the essay [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Loop variable 'x' to increment by 1 until it reaches the value of the number 'num'.
While looping check if num is divisible by x by using modulo. If remainder is 0, stop.

Ex.

```
mod = 1;
while (mod != 0)
{
mod = num % x;
x++;
}
```

Tadah! Prime Number checker... Not sure if there's a faster way than this though.

Answer (score 0):

I made a much faster algorithm recently.. it can easily hash out a 14 digit number in a few seconds.  Just paste this code into anywhere that accepts javascript code and run it..  Keep in mind that the version of javascript must be recent as of this post as it has to have BigInteger support in order to do these operations.  Typically the latest browsers (Chrome, firefox, Safari)  will support features like this.. but its anyone's guess if other browsers such as Microsoft IE will support it properly.

--

The algorithm works by using a combination of some of the previously mentioned algorithmic ideas.

However...

This algorithm was actually GENERATED by visualizing sets of prime numbers and multiplying them by various different values and then performing various  mod operations to those values and using those numbers to create a 3d representation of all prime numbers which revealed the true patterns that exist within prime number sets.

```
var prime_nums = [2n,3n,5n,7n,11n,13n,17n,19n,23n,29n,31n,37n,41n,43n,47n,53n,59n,61n,67n,71n,73n,79n,83n,89n,97n,101n,103n,107n,109n,113n,127n,131n,137n,139n,149n,151n,157n,163n,167n,173n,179n,181n,191n,193n,197n,199n,211n,223n,227n,229n,233n,239n,241n,251n,257n,263n,269n,271n,277n,281n,283n,293n,307n,311n,313n,317n,331n,337n,347n,349n,353n,359n,367n,373n,379n,383n,389n,397n,401n,409n,419n,421n,431n,433n,439n,443n,449n,457n,461n,463n,467n,479n,487n,491n];

function isHugePrime(_num) {
  var num = BigInt(_num);
  var square_nums = [BigInt(9) ,  BigInt(25) , BigInt(49) ,BigInt(77) , BigInt(1) , BigInt(35) , BigInt(55)];

  var z = BigInt(30);
  var y = num % z;

  var yList = [];
  yList.push(num % BigInt(78));
  var idx_guess = num / 468n;
  var idx_cur = 0;
  while ((z * z) < num) {
      z += BigInt(468);
      var l = prime_nums[prime_nums.length - 1]

         while (l < (z / BigInt(3))) {
                idx_cur++;
                l += BigInt(2);
                if (isHugePrime(l)) {
                    prime_nums.push(l);
                }
      }
      y = num % z;
      yList.push(y);


    }
  for (var i=0; i<yList.length; i++) {
      var y2 = yList[i];
      y = y2;
      if (prime_nums.includes(num)) { return true; }
      if ((prime_nums.includes(y)) || (y == BigInt(1)) || (square_nums.includes(y))) {

                          if ((y != BigInt(1)) && ((num % y) != BigInt(0))) {

                             for (var t=0; t<prime_nums.length; t++) {
                                  var r = prime_nums[t];
                                  if ((num % r) == BigInt(0)) { return false; }
                                }

                              return true;
                            }
                          if (y == BigInt(1)) {
                              var q = BigInt(num);
                              for (var t=0; t<prime_nums.length; t++) {
                                  var r = prime_nums[t];
                                  if ((q % r) == BigInt(0)) { return false; }
                                }


                              return true;

                            }

                       }

    }
  return false;
}
```